# Query not outputting all relevant results from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to output all relevant values from my database using the code below. For some reason, some information is not output that should be, and I don't know why.

I'm guessing there is something wrong with my query?

```
$result = mysql_query(
        "SELECT 

        tbl_status.id as statID, 
        tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
        tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
        tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
        tbl_status.date as statDATE,

        tbl_users.id as usrID, 
        tbl_users.name as usrNAME,

        tbl_photos.profile as photosPROFILE,
        tbl_photos.photo_link as photoLINK,
        tbl_photos.default_photo as photoDEFAULT 

        FROM tbl_status 
        INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id

        INNER JOIN tbl_photos ON tbl_photos.profile = tbl_users.id 
        WHERE tbl_status.deleted = '0' AND tbl_photos.default_photo = '1'
        ORDER BY tbl_status.date desc;

        ");
```

Comment: We need more information. Whats in your tables? what do you expect to get out of the query? What are you actually getting out of the query?

Comment: I have a 3 tables 
[users][status][photos]

They have been 'joined' as to get the users name, status and profile pic

All status' should be output but only certain ones are.

Comment: If you want all statuses to be output, why do you have a `where` clause that filters on a field in that table?

Comment: that is to ensure the user has not deleted the status (note that status' are not actually deleted, just deactivated in the database with a column containing either 1 or 0)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, here are four possible reasons you're not seeing all statuses:

1. You're using an inner join to `tbl_photos`, so any user that doesn't have a photo will be excluded.
2. You're using an inner join to `tbl_users`, so any status that doesn't relate to at least one user (and the user *must* have a photo - see #1) will be excluded.
3. You're filtering on `tbl_photos.default_photo = '1'`, so any photo with `tbl_photos.default_photo <> '1'` will be excluded. Because of the inner joins, this will also exclude the associated user and possibly exclude the associated status.
4. You're filtering on `tbl_status.deleted = '0'`, so any status with `delete <> '0'` will be excluded. Obvious, but worth mentioning.

Try this: change `INNER JOIN tbl_users` to `LEFT JOIN tbl_users`, and change `INNER JOIN tbl_photos` to `LEFT JOIN tbl_photos`. If that doesn't give you the results you expect, please post sample data and expected results.

Comment: There should be 10 possible status' to output. Only 8 are showing. That's with the join changed to 'Left'

Comment: Ah, but you are right though now I look more into it! There are 2 posts there that were uploaded by a user with no profile pic - those results do not get output.
How can I then output those also?

Comment: The left-joined photos will have a `default_photo` value of null, so you could also try changing the `tbl_photos.default_photo = '1'` condition to `(tbl_photos.default_photo IS NULL OR tbl_photos.default_photo = '1')`. If you do, it's *very* important to include the parentheses.

Comment: Good, I'm learning new things all the time. That worked dude :)